# Brezis' exercise 1.23.6: is the assumption $D\left(\varphi^{*}\right) \cap D\left(\psi^{*}\right) \neq \emptyset$ redundant?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, convex-analysis

Let $(E, |\cdot|)$ be a normed vector space. For $\varphi: E \to \mathbb R \cup \{\pm\infty\}$, one defines its **domain** as $D(\varphi) := \{x\in E : \varphi(x) \neq \pm\infty\}$, and its **strict epigraph** as $\operatorname{epist} \varphi := \{(x, \lambda) \in E \times \mathbb{R} : \varphi(x)<\lambda\}$. Notice that $\varphi$ is convex if and only if $\operatorname{epist} \varphi$ is convex. For $\varphi, \psi: E \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$, one defines their **inf-convolution** of $\varphi$ and $\psi$ as
$$
(\varphi \nabla \psi)(x)=\inf _{y \in E}\{\varphi(x-y)+\psi(y)\} \quad \forall x \in E.
$$

Notice that $(\varphi \nabla \psi)(x)$ may take the values $\pm \infty$, and $(\varphi \nabla \psi)(x) < +\infty \iff x \in D(\varphi)+D(\psi)$.

At page 26 from Brezis' *Functional Analysis*, there is

> **Exercise 1.23.6** Let $\varphi, \psi: E \to \mathbb R \cup \{+\infty\}$. If $D\left(\varphi^{*}\right) \cap D\left(\psi^{*}\right) \neq \emptyset$, then $\operatorname{epist}(\varphi \nabla \psi) = (\operatorname{epist} \varphi)+(\operatorname{epist} \psi)$. Here $\varphi^*$ is the [convex conjugate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_conjugate#Definition) of $\varphi$.

Below I **don't** use $D\left(\varphi^{*}\right) \cap D\left(\psi^{*}\right) \neq \emptyset$ anywhere. Could you confirm if this assumption is redundant, or I miss something subtle?

---

**My attempt:** Let $(x_1, \lambda_1) \in \operatorname{epist} \varphi$ and $(x_1, \lambda_1) \in \operatorname{epist} \psi$. Then
\begin{align}
(\varphi \nabla \psi) (x_1+x_2) &= \inf_{y\in E} \{ \varphi (x_1+x_2-y) + \psi (y)\} \\
&\le \varphi (x_1) + \psi (x_2) \\
&< \lambda_1 + \lambda_2.
\end{align}

So $(x_1+x_2, \lambda_1+\lambda_2) \in \operatorname{epist}(\varphi \nabla \psi)$. Hence $(\operatorname{epist} \varphi)+(\operatorname{epist} \psi) \subset \operatorname{epist}(\varphi \nabla \psi)$. Let $(x, \lambda) \in \operatorname{epist}(\varphi \nabla \psi)$. Then there is $y \in E$ such that $\varphi (x-y) + \psi (y) < \lambda$. Clearly, $\varphi (x-y),\psi (y) \neq +\infty$. Let
$$
\varepsilon := \frac{\lambda - (\varphi (x-y) + \psi (y))}{2}>0.
$$

Notice that $(x-y, \varphi(x-y) + \varepsilon) \in \operatorname{epist} \varphi$ and $(y, \psi(y) + \varepsilon) \in \operatorname{epist} \psi$. We have
$$
x = (x-y)+ y
\quad \text{and} \quad
\lambda = (\varphi(x-y) + \varepsilon)) + (\psi(y) + \varepsilon).
$$

So $\operatorname{epist}(\varphi \nabla \psi) \subset (\operatorname{epist} \varphi)+(\operatorname{epist} \psi)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is fine. I guess that this assumption is included to have that $\varphi \nabla \psi$ maps into $(-\infty,\infty]$ (and does not take the value $-\infty$).